# ADF: Derived column with multiple (true) conditions returning string array

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, multiple-conditions, derived-column

I have the following problem in a Data Factory data flow:
I have two pipelines that extract data: one daily on weekdays, and one monthly on the first working day of each month.
In the data flow I would like to insert a derived column, 'Frequency', that based on the date value in the 'DataRef' column, assigns a predefined array of string (separated by '|') values according to this logic:

- if it is executed in the daily execution pipeline and DataRef is a weekday then 'daily';
- if it's Friday then 'daily | weekly';
- if it's the last Friday of the month 'daily | weekly | monthly'.
- If run in the monthly execution pipeline, all data will have 'monthly' frequency and value

For now I tried this expression (the third condition is not implemented), but obviously only the first condition is verified

[image]

and this is the result returned

[image]

But I would expect, e.g., where DateRef is 2023-07-14 (Friday), Frequency 'daily | weekly', or where DateRef is 2023-06-30 (last Friday of June 2023), Frequency 'daily | weekly | monthly'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, you are using the same expression in two dataflows and expecting the above result?

Comment: Hi @RakeshGovindula! Thanks for your concern.
No, I'm using this expression in a derived column of a data flow used by two pipelines, one executed every weekday, and one executed once a month on the first day of the month.

No, I expect the result written below the image. The one in the image is what is returned to me by the expression as I wrote it in the image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below expression to achieve the result.

```
toString(
    concat(
        iif(instr($pipelineName,'Monthly')!=0,'monthly',iif(dayOfWeek(DateRef) >=2 || dayOfWeek(DateRef) <=6, "daily",''))
        ,iif(instr($pipelineName,'Daily')!=0 && (dayOfWeek(DateRef) == 6),' | weekly',''),iif(instr($pipelineName,'Daily')!=0 && dayOfWeek(DateRef) ==6 && (minus(dayOfMonth(lastDayOfMonth(DateRef)),dayOfMonth(DateRef))<=6),' | monthly','')
    )
)
```

[image]

**Result when pipeline name is `"Daily"`**:

[image]

**Result when pipeline name is `Monthly`:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh! I appreciate you for your support. The expression works perfectly as I wished.